# Changing section names in Django CMS admin panel

Tags: django-cms

Is it possible to change a section name in the Django CMS admin panel? I am using cmsplugin_blog which appears in the admin panel as a section named 'Cmsplugin_Blog'. I'd like to rename the title to 'News' since I'm using this module for news publishing.

Can I also change the the word 'Entry' that describes each individual entry for some other word?

Answer (score 0):

An ugly way to do that would be to monkey patch `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` on `cmsplugin_blog.Entry._meta`. As for the section name, I don't know how to do that.